# Using gable vent inside roof ventilation system

Tags: ventilation

I have three powered roof vents and all three went bad within two months of each other.  Wanted to replace the motor from attic side but, just about impossible to take fan blades off without bending attachment strips, prying, pulling, then trying to take allen screw off fan shaft.  Wondering if I can just take fan out of housing with all its attachments and just mount a gable vent over hole?  The roof rain covering still be there.  Seems to me it would work. What do you think??

Answer (score 0):

You would get some natural ventilation because hot air rises and most roofs have soffits installed. The problem is that you won't get anywhere near the air flow you would achieve with the three roof fans working correctly. You should be able to drop the motor and blades down from the housing and replace the motor and or the whole assembly.